# Gstreamer last frame freeze when no internet connection

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer

I`m using Gstreamer to reach rtsp stream. When i use it with internet connection and with my lan - its ok, when i lost lan connection. But when i use it without internet connection, all my program just freeze for 20s.

I have already tried to change all timeout var - it doesnt work!

```
Pipeline: s = “rtspsrc protocols=tcp location=” + s + " latency=0 tcp-timeout=1 buffer-mode=1 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=25/1 ! appsink";
```

What should i do?

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/gstreamer-last-frame-freeze-when-no-internet-connection/11089

Answer (score 1):

If the source of your rtsp stream is hosted on your lan then your rtsp source may require a internet connection to operate. Some of the cheaper IP cameras require a constant connection the internet to operate.

Your gstreamer pipeline looks okay.

you can try the following commands to rule out that your pipeline is the problem:

```
gst-discoverer-1.0 <source_uri>
```

and

```
gst-play-1.0 <source_uri>
```

gst-discoverer-1.0 will tell you information about the source, you should run it while you are connected to the internet, then disconnect from the internet and run it again to see if there are any changes.

gst-play-1.0 will automagically create the correct pipeline and display the video to your monitor.